# Does two phase locking actually prevent lost updates?

Tags: database, concurrency, conflict-serializability

Two phase locking is [claimed](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two-phase_locking) to be a solution for ensuring serial execution. However, I'm not sure how it adequately solves the lost update problem during a read-modify-write cycle. I may be overlooking / misunderstanding the locking mechanism here!

For example, assuming we have a database running using 2PL:

Given a SQL table `account` with an integer column `email_count`, lets assume we have the following record in our database:

```
| ID | email_count |

| ----- | ----- |

| 1    | 0  |
```

Now lets assume we have two concurrently executing transactions, `T1` and `T2`. Both transactions will read `email_count` from `accounts` where ID = 1, increment the count value by 1, and write back the result.

Here's one scenario in which 2PL does *not* seem to address the lost update problem (T1 represents transaction 1):

**T1** -> Obtains a non-exclusive, shared read lock. Read from `email_count` for ID = 1.  Gets the result 0. Application sets a new value (0 + 1 = 1) for a later write.

**T2** -> Also obtains a non-exclusive, shared read lock. Read from `email_count' for ID = 1.  Gets the result 0. Application also sets a new value (using a now stale pre-condition), which is 1 (0 + 1 = 1).

**T1** -> Obtains an exclusive write lock and writes the new value (1) to our record. This will block T2 from writing.

**T2** -> Attempts to obtain write lock so it can write the value 1, but is forced to wait for T1 to complete its transaction and release all of T1's own locks.

Now here's my question:

Once T1 completes and releases its locks (during the "shrink" phase of our 2PL), **T2 *still* has a stale `email_count` value of 1!** So when T1 completes and T2 proceeds with its write (with `email_count` = 1), we'll "lose" the original update from T1.

Comment: What's the specific database? Locks are managed in different ways in different database engines.

Comment: @TheImpaler yeah i figured the implementation would be different across engines, but the literature on 2PL from a theoretical point is making a claim about serializability that seems agnostic of implementations. If it helps tho,I typically use postgres or mysql / innoDB

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If T2 has read-lock, T1 cannot acquire an exclusive lock until T2 releases the read lock. Thus, the execution sequence you describe cannot happen. T1 would be denied the write lock, and T2 continues the transaction.

Comment: Hmmm so T1 acquires a read lock and T2 ALSO acquires a read lock. So they both read the existing value at the same time (this is the crux of the problem). The exclusive lock that T2 attempts to acquire is denied _after_ it has already read a stale value.

Unless you're suggesting that all the necessary locks are acquired _prior_ to any of the read queries executing?

Comment: All I am saying is that the scenario you describe cannot happen. If there is an active read-lock, another transaction cannot get a write-lock.

Comment: You're saying that my description of this step above: 

```T2 -> Attempts to obtain write lock so it can write the value 1, but is forced to wait for T1 to complete its transaction and release all of T1's own locks.
``

Isn't possible? I thought if there's an active lock, the other transaction will wait rather than just abort. Is that not the case?

Comment: If a transaction cannot lock all necessary locks at the first phase, it should fail instead of waiting. Otherwise, it would read stale values. Thus for a correct implementation, T1 should fail at the third step.

Comment: Ah, gotcha! This sounds a lot like https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conservative_two-phase_locking. So, the transaction will, ahead of time, acquire all the locks it needs. So the other transaction will be forced to either fail or wait for the first transaction to complete entirely. Does that sound right? Thank you for clarifying btw!

Answer (score 1):

> T1 -> Obtains an exclusive write lock and writes the new value (1) to
> our record. This will block T2 from writing.

Above step cannot happen because T2 has already had shared read lock, so T1 should wait until T2 release shared read lock.

But, T2 can't release shared read lock.

Because, according to 2PL, if T2 want to release shared read lock, T2 should get write lock first.

But T2 can't get write lock because T1 has already had shared read lock.

So,, yes, it's deadlock. That's why 2PL prevent lost update. Even if it may produce deadlock..